# JSON values not showing properly

Tags: php, json, ajax

I wrote a php script which accept POST request from ajax and give the response back. All working fine. But the receiving string split letter by letter I can't understand what is the reason.

Here is my AJAX code,

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
          console.log($("#search_bar").val());
          var dataV;
          var htmlText = '';
          var containerbootsrap = '';
          var filename = '';
          var index_no;
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  crossDomain: true,
                  url: "http://localhost:8090/ontology/setText",
                  data: $("#search_bar").val(),
                  contentType: 'text/plain',
                  // dataType: "json",
                  success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                      console.log('data');
                      console.log(data);

                      for( var item in data) {
                        console.log ("item: " + item);
                        console.log ("data: " + data[item]);
                        index_no = data[item];

                        // htmlText += '<div class="div-conatiner">';
                        // htmlText += '<p class="p-name"> Name: ' + data[item] + '</p>';
                        // htmlText += '<img class="imageload" src="' + data[item] +  '" />';
                        // htmlText += '</div>';

                        // filename = data[item].replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')

                        $.ajax({
                          data: 'index_no=' + index_no,
                          url: 'retrivedata.php',
                          method: 'POST', // or GET
                          dataType: 'json',
                          success: function(msg) {
                                    console.log(msg);
                                    for(var item in msg){
                                      console.log ("item: " + item);
                                      console.log ("data: " + msg[item]); 
                                    }

                                    $('#home').hide();

                                    containerbootsrap += '<div class = "container" id="search_container">';
                                    containerbootsrap += '<div class = "row homepage">';
                                    containerbootsrap += '<div class = "col-md-5 col-md-offset-3">';
                                    containerbootsrap += '<a href="#" class="thumbnail">';
                                    containerbootsrap += '<img class="imageload" src="' + msg +  '" />';
                                    containerbootsrap += '<h3 id="video_name"> ' + filename + ' </h3>'
                                    containerbootsrap += '</a>';
                                    containerbootsrap += '</div>';
                                    containerbootsrap += '</div>';
                                    containerbootsrap += '</div>';

                                    $('body').append(containerbootsrap);

                                  }
                        });

                        // $.post('retrivedata.php', { num: 5 }, function(result) {
                        //       alert(result);
                        // });

                        // $('#home').hide();
                      }

                      // $('body').append(containerbootsrap);

                  },
                  error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                      console.log( jqXhr );
                      alert(jqXhr)
                  }

              });
        });
```

php code is below

```
<?php
$index_no = $_POST["index_no"];
// echo $index_no * 2;

include('dbConnection.php');
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM video_data WHERE index_no =    $index_no");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $imagePath = $row['thumbnail_url'];
    $videoPath = $row['video_url'];
    // echo $imagePath;
    // echo $videoPath;
    echo json_encode($imagePath);
}

?>
```

I need the output as : 'imagepath'
but it is giving the output as split letter by letter.

here is the real output

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6EIt.png)

but i need the output in one line. like /video_frames/bb/frame136.jpg 
please help me to figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: Can you post the output?, and just a tip, you could tell in php to the browser what to expect with `header("Content-Type: application/json");`

Comment: Try to do `echo json_encode($imagePath);` outside the while, and if you are expecting just one row is not necessary to use `while`

Comment: If I remember right json_encode has unpredictable results when presented a `string`.  Can you put that string into an array like `array($imagePath)`

Comment: As well try what @Forbs said and if you don't need a loop don't use `while`

Comment: No I need a loop because I want to retrieve all the values within the db. because index_no is having random values like 1,2,4,8,3 so i need to get all values which is equal to the index number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the php code where you're returning the value you need to specify an array not an string. The variable there $imagePath seems to be a string. You can do something like this.

```
echo json_encode(array('result' => $imagePath));
```

This will give you your result in the 'result' key. You can parse it and use it.

Comment: JugalK now values are assigned to the result key. But I do not understand how to get it to a variable in the client. Please help

Comment: {"result":"\/video_frames\/bb\/frame136.jpg"} json is giving like that. I try to read from the                 for( var item in obj) {
                                          console.log ("item: " + item);
                                          console.log ("data: " + obj[item]);
                                        } but it is not working

Comment: Working charm. Thank you for the help JugalK

Comment: Anytime. Sorry couldn't  reply to your comments earlier. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the returned JSON string into an array.  One way to do it is by adding `data = $.parseJSON(data)` in the ajax success callback (highlighted below).  I was able to recreate the same thing you're seeing and adding this line fixed it.  Hope this helps.  [parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

```
...
    success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                    console.log('data');
                    console.log(data);
```

> `data = $.parseJSON(data);`

```
                for( var item in data) {
                    console.log ("item: " + item);
                    console.log ("data: " + data[item]);
                    index_no = data[item];
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this is not the case. The second ajax call having some issues.

Comment: Did you try adding `msg = $.parseJSON(msg);` before the  `...for(var item in msg){...`  loop in the second ajax call?

Comment: Yes it is giving an error unexpected token by the jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to check the type of value in variable you are getting first like

```
data = '{"name": "Bhushan"}' //string value 
data = {name: "Bhushan"}     //object value

//for testing you can use either, this will make it unbreakable for this context

if(typeof(data) == 'string')
{ 
   data = JSON.parse(data)
}
//rest of code
```

This will give your module good stability otherwise you may get ***json parse unexpected token o***.